# Excel - Working with Merged Cells Dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

Good afternoon, hope you're all doing well.

Our Data Warehouse is exporting the data in kind of a weird format, using merged cells, which we have to clean weekly so we can work with it.

[image: Sample Data]

In the screenshot you can find the setup, which relies on merged cells, instead of copying the partner, dates, brand & zone code.

I've created a formula that specifies that if the row above is blank, then, it finds the next cell further on top which has text and copies it, but it's a little unreliable, it goes like this:

```
=IF([@Date]="",B23,[@Date])

=IF([@Date]="",B24,[@Date])
```

Since `B23` is not blank, then it assumes its value. Then, the next one, since `B24` is blank, then it copies `B23`. Then, since `B25` is blank, it copies `B24`, which already has the date value.

It works, but it seems like there must be a better way to achieve this dynamically, for the dates and the other merged columns, which have the same pattern with the merged cells.
I have explored some Power Query solutions, but yielding no results. Note that when importing this data with Power Query, the merged cells simply come as "null".

Comment: If you haven't already, I would explore all the options for the data warehouse export to make sure there isn't a "data only" option. This would be the most efficient path. Most exports have a ".csv" or other data only option. Otherwise I don't know of a better way for filling in the data unless you want to set something up in VBA.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have no such option to export this kind of data, at this point. I can work with VBA, but only at a very basic level. I'm able to understand the code, but writing it takes me quite a long time, at this point. So I'm not sure I would want to go through that path, do you have some specific example source for the code I could use?

Comment: No, I don't have any examples for this scenario and it would take me a while to put something together. Hopefully someone else has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your data in an Excel structured table (which seems like because the formula you posted) look in power query for the command transform and fill down.

I currently only have installed the spanish version, but you can look for the commands in English.

[image]

Here is a tutorial I found:
https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/fill-values-using-power-query/

Answer (score 0):

A basic VBA approach:

```
Sub UnMerge()

    Dim c As Range, m As Range, v

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If c.MergeCells Then
            v = c.Value
            Set m = c.MergeArea
            c.UnMerge
            m.Value = v
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```